# Apache2 / PHP 7.4-fpm not downloading files but displaying them in browser

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache2, files

Apache2 using PHP 7.4-fpm is not downloading files but displaying them in browser

Take a look here

https://www.files.olokos.pl/wl/?id=MCeDihTf5XvHq8RCqbh81rlRoAACLIL8

I am not sure what happened as it worked perfectly before, but now it's only displaying files inside of the browser, not downloading them.

Answer (score 0):

The headers are not ok. Instead of `content-disposition: inline; filename="nolockscreen.suprx"` it should be `content-disposition: attachment; filename="nolockscreen.suprx"`. This should be set by the php application.

```
$ curl -I https://www.files.olokos.pl/wl/?id=MCeDihTf5XvHq8RCqbh81rlRoAACLIL8
HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 25 Dec 2019 01:22:57 GMT
server: Apache
content-disposition: inline; filename="nolockscreen.suprx"
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
last-modified: Sun, 03 Nov 2019 03:41:00 GMT
etag: "7e5-59668f7b2ab00"
content-length: 2021
```

The file is shown in the browser because of `inline`. for more details see the [Mozilla documentation about `Content-Disposition` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

You can see how php-fpm is setting the `Content-Disposition` header by running as `root` user:

```
strace -fyp $(pgrep php-fpm|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g') -s 30000 |& grep -i 'Content-Disposition:'
```

Comment: [This](https://feedback.filerun.com/communities/1/topics/813-files-data-directly-displayed-in-browser-instead-of-downloading-the-file)
 is the response I got from the php application developer

Comment: Updated my answer hot to test how the header is set by php-fpm

Comment: when I execute this command then nothing happens, its not doing anything, but running.

Comment: Do you have `strace` installed? If not install it with: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y strace`

Comment: I do have it installed.

Comment: You need to load/refresh that page during the tracing.

Comment: I did that, but it's not doing anything
https://prnt.sc/qffpuh

Comment: Save the trace in a file and search for HTTP response headers in the file: `strace -fyp $(pgrep php-fpm|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g') -s 30000 -o strace-php-fpm.txt`

Comment: Here's the file, its pretty lenghty, I'm not sure what exactly to look for
https://www.files.olokos.pl/wl/?id=cJSfGeIMLpDykcj9gjtp9Dg3eRLmkzdA

Comment: above link works only because it's made using 
"prevent browser from opening the files"